# How to connect two different height water tank on pump?

Tags: water, pipe, sump-pump, water-tank

I have a two.different size water tanks, 1500 liter and 500 liter. Both water tank height and width is different.

1500 liter tank width-    49.5” height- 56”
500 liter tank width-  36.5”  height- 36”

I want to connect both water tank with one water pump. Water tank will be installed in roof in my house, one the other hand pump will be installed in ground floor.

Can anyone give me the full installing process?

Comment: the sentence about where the tanks are installed appears to be missing some words. ... it is unclear where the second tank is installed

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is to mount the tanks so that the water surfaces are level when the tanks are full. This means that they can be connected, without valves etc, together directly to the pump inlet.

If the full surfaces are not level, then one tank will fill the other and may cause an overflow, unless one-way valves etc are fitted.

Comment: Can you give me the drawing of installation?

Comment: No, because I don't know any of the other constraints you are working with - floor strength, beam spacing etc. I described, in simple terms, what yu need to achieve. How you do that is up to you and it is your responsibility to make sure it is safe.